# picture load asynchronously

Tags: visual-web-part, ajax

I have a picture that is larger than the viewable area... and I need to add a scrollbar to the picture so that I can load the picture as per the scrollbar. I need to show the picture in a visual web part.

I cannot load the whole picture at once .. but load it in part with scrollbar as the control!!

I believe I need to use Ajax to load the picture and add scrollbar for it. I need to use visual web part and building a web part.

Comment: That would take a lot of AJAX & jQuery to cover. Is there a reason why you don't put a `DIV` as a container around the `img` and then set fixed width and height on that `DIV` and then just put css `overflow` on it?

Comment: I did do that... I did put the scrollbar and placed css overflow on it but the requirement was to load the picture asynchronously... so that the loading of picture is dependent on the scrollbar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use jquery:

Scroll to detect the page scrolling:

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Offset to determine page position:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Ajax Get to load the picture:

api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/